# Can the size of a stretchable button image be animated in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-animation

I'm creating a UIButton with a **stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:**

I would like to change it's size smoothly with Core Animation like so:

```
float shrinkFactor = 0.2;
NSTimeInterval slowSpeed = 5.0;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:slowSpeed];

UIButton *thisButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
thisButton.frame = CGRectMake(thisButton.frame.origin.x, thisButton.frame.origin.y, buttonStretchedWidth * shrinkFactor, thisButton.frame.size.height);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The button image size doesn't animate, it just snaps to the new size.

When I make the **backgroundColor** of the button visible, I see the frame itself animates correctly.

Am I missing something or is the image stretching not animatable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never been able to get image stretching to update continuously. Try splitting your image up into the caps and center areas and create eight or nine `UIImageView` subviews with the appropriate `autoresizingMask` set. E.g. the top-right corner view should have `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`, the bottom-center view (getting stretched) should have `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`, and so on. Views are pretty cheap on the iPhone OS, once they're created, so I don't think you'll see a performance hit unless you're animating a half-dozen buttons at once. Make sure to make whatever you can opaque, though—compositing non-opaque views is pretty expensive.